# Nikon F-mount lens adapters for Sony E-mount with fewest compromises

Tags: equipment-recommendation, nikon, sony, lens-mount, lens-adapter

I presently use a Nikon D600, which is an fx body. As you can imagine I have plenty of F-mount fx glass laying around. I am looking at getting a Sony mirrorless as a portable second body for when a d600 is too bulky or too inappropriate.

Clearly I will need some actual E-mount glass, but I was looking to minimise the initial outlay.

Are there are good, no compromises, or fewer compromises, Nikon glass to Sony E-mount adapters that would still allow for autofocus, metering, and aperture control? Clearly autofocus is not possible on older Nikon D lenses, but I was hoping that someone has managed to find one that works with the internal-motor G lenses.

Comment: As an aside, have you looked at the Nikon 1 and the [FT1](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/823722-REG/Nikon_3613_FT1_Mount_Adapter.html) adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a D610 and a NEX 5R, so I'm in a similar situation.

Just buy the cheapest adapter that has mechanical aperture control for G lenses. Forget about autofocus; even if you find the most expensive adapter that allows autofocus, it would not be very good.

The beauty of Sony E bodies is the full-time LiveView AND the really nicely implemented focus peaking feature. You will have a really easy time manual focusing with the Sony E body.

You don't have to worry too much about metering too, because the Sony E is always on LiveView.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! This does seem like the best solution currently. Was hoping for better news from experienced hands since it seems like Canon EF lenses do have a working auto-adapter.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.sonyalpharumors.com/first-video-showing-the-nikon-f-to-sony-e-mount-autofocus-adapter/

I'm waiting for more news on the adapter shown in the link above. I really don't want to sell all my Nikon glass but I do want to change to mirrorless.

All rights, credit and thanks to Sony Alpha Rumors for getting the information about this adapter out to the public.